# JSP drop-down not populating

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to populate a drop down using a simple query. I tried printing the query output on the console and it works fine, but it does not seem to populate the drop down.

Here are my java files

```
    package testpkg;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.*;


public class Facility
{
    public Statement st; 
    public void get_connection()
     {
         try
         {
             Class.forName("oracle.driver.OracleDriver");
         }
         catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
         {
            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC driver missing. Connection to Database failed!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
         }
         System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered");
         Connection con = null;

         try
         {
             con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.201.301.111:1521:PIC1","ID","PASS");
         }
         catch(SQLException e)
         {
             System.out.println("Connection Failed!! Check console for error code!!");
             e.printStackTrace();
             return;
         }
         if(con !=null)
         {
             System.out.println("Database Connection Successful!");
         }
         try
         {
             con.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e){}
     }   
}
```

Here's the other java class

```
package testpkg;

import java.sql.*;

public class state extends Facility
{
    public ResultSet getStates()
    {   
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try
        {
            get_connection();
            rs= st.executeQuery("select org.org_name from organization org");

        }
        catch (Exception e){}
        return (rs);
    }
}
```

Here's the JSP code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@page import = "java.io.PrintWriter" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="testpkg.state"%>

<%
try
{
    state s = new state();          //initializing the state.java class
    ResultSet rs= s.getStates();    //calling the method getStates from state.java
    String data;%>

    <select id="combos" name="org">

    <%while(rs.next())
    {
        data = rs.getString("ORG_NAME");%>
        <option value= "<%=data %>"> <%=data%> </option>            
    <%}%>
    </select>
<%}
catch(Exception e){}%>
```

Comment: Not yet. I'm still trying. The dropdown shows up as blank.

Comment: in your java class you have said `select org.org_name` org_name small letters,whereas in you JSP `rs.getString("ORG_NAME");`the column ORG_NAME is in caps..

Comment: also check this `select org.org_name from organization org` there should be a dot between organization and org `select org.org_name from organization.org`

Comment: I tried both the suggestions (ORG_NAME in small and organization.org) but I dont see the drop down getting populated. However, when I saw the console, I noticed this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.driver.OracleDriver. I've already inlcuded classes12.jar in the library.

Comment: add this to catch `catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace()}` and let me know what u get in the console

Comment: also try this query `select org.org_name from organization.org` on your oracle terminal and tell me what u get

Comment: select org.org_name from organization.org - throws an error on the SQL developer saying "table or view does not exist". And the Catch clause throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver error.

Comment: not yet. Still trying.

Comment: wat error are u getting?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. I was closing the db connection before the dropwdown got populated and that was the reason it was coming up as blank.